# Installing QGIS 3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-3, ubuntu

QGIS 3.0 [is released](http://blog.qgis.org/2018/02/23/qgis-3-0-girona-is-released/). However, in the [download page](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html), there does not seem to be an entry (for Ubuntu (16.04) at least):

> Latest Release    2.18.x Las Palmas (new LTR)
>
> https://qgis.org/debian
>
> ...
>
> Long Term Release Repository  2.14.x Essen (previous LTR)
>
> ...
>
> Development Version   2.99.x master [4]
>
> https://qgis.org/debian-nightly
>
> ...

Which repository should be used to get the new QGIS 3.0?

Comment: For someone interested in QGIS3 for Windows, this is the download link: https://download.osgeo.org/qgis/windows/?C=M;O=D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for the record, as of 02/24/2018, changing the repository from

```
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly xenial main
```

to

```
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntugis  xenial main
```

, and `apt-get remove/install qgis` worked. This installs qgis 3.0 and replaces 2.99dev.

The debian source:
`deb https://qgis.org/debian xenial main`
, however, does not seem to be update-to-date at present, and installs qgis-2.18.

Answer (score 3):

Even if the website text is not updated yet, https://qgis.org/debian already contains 3.0:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of June 2018, QGIS 3.2 installs on Ubuntu 16.04 with the following repositories:

```
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main
```

ubuntugis-unstable is critical, as `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu xenial main` does currently not contain a recent enough libgdal20 (it contains 2.1.3, but >= 2.2.0 is needed).

Comment: ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis (i.e. ubuntugis-stable) was never meant to be used with QGIS repos.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize: Now during the transition to QGIS 3.0, on Ubuntu 16.04 and similar systems there are three possibilities:

1. Using the ubuntugis repository you get updated to 3.0 but with no GRASS support. The GRASS plugin loads OK, but no access to GRASS maps in QGIS.
2. If you use the debian repo you stay at 2.18.16 (the current "LTR") but also without GRASS support.
3. And with the ubuntugis-unstable ([ppa](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu)) repository you get reverted back to 2.14.22, and only in this version GRASS support **is** available.

Of course `apt-get purge` is needed after changing repos to switch between the different versions. So scratch item #2 above...

**Edit**: In the last few days, the recommended [ltr](https://qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr) repo now offers QGIS 2.18.17 and support for GRASS maps has returned. So scratch item #2 above.